# Oracle Nested Grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

The question is: For each day, list the User ID who has read the most number of messages.

```
user_id   msgID   read_date
 1         1       10 
 1         2       10
 2         2       10
 2         2       23
 3         2       23
```

I believe the date is an outer group and user_id is an inner group, but how to do group nesting in sql? Or somehow avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a task for a Window Function:

```
select *
from
 (
   select user_id, read_date, count(*) as cnt, 
      rank()
      over (partition by read_date           -- each day
            order by count(*) desc) as rnk  -- maximum number
   from tab
   group by user_id, read_date
 ) dt 
where rnk = 1
```

This might return multiple users for one with the same maximum count, if you want just one (randomly) switch to `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: Great answer @dnoeth, but you've got a spello on `partition` :)

Comment: @dnoeth This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id
from
(
    select user_id,count(msgID)
    from table
    group by read_date
)
where rownum <= 1;
```